# R: SVM parallel

Tags: r, svm, parallel.foreach

I am working on a project about text mining using SVM. The dfm(similar to document-term matrix) is huge (50MB)and it takes forever to run the SVM, so I thought about running it in parallel. 
First I tried parallelSVM() in "parallelSVM" package. But the problem was the dfm was too big to be converted to a data.frame (I confirmed with the author and he said it indeed converts the dfm to a data.frame.)
Then I tried to do the parallel SVM manually.

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
library(parallel)

cl<-makeCluster(detectCores()) #change the 4 to your number of CPU cores
registerDoSNOW(cl)

split_training<-sort(rank(1:nrow(trainingtfidf))%%4)

svm_model_para<-foreach(i=unique(split_training),
                         .combine=c,.packages=c("e1071", "quanteda")) %dopar% {
                           svm(trainingtfidf[split_training== i], as.factor(trainingset$PD.Code[split_training== i]), kernel="radial", epsilon = 0.01, tolerance = 0.01)
                         }
stopCluster(cl)
```

It returned a large list instead of a large SVM so I couldn't use it to the crossvalidation (with predict() ).
Does anyone has any idea? I appreciate it!

PS:
The dataset is huge so I don't know how to generate the example dataset here. But I still put the example with three documents here so people can understand what's in the SVM code. Thanks,

```
description <- c("From month 2 the AST and total bilirubine were not measured.", "16:OTHER - COMMENT REQUIRED IN COMMENT COLUMN;07/02/2004/GENOTYPING;SF- genotyping consent not offered until T4.",  "M6 is 13 days out of the visit window")
code <- c(4,3,6)
example <- data.frame(description, code)

library(quanteda)
trainingcorpus <- corpus(example$description)

trainingdfm <- dfm(trainingcorpus, verbose = TRUE, stem=TRUE, toLower=TRUE, removePunct= TRUE, removeSeparators=TRUE, language="english", ignoredFeatures = stopwords("english"), removeNumbers=TRUE, ngrams = 2)

# tf-idf
trainingtfidf <- tfidf(trainingdfm, normalize=TRUE)

sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tm_0.6-2       openxlsx_3.0.0 magrittr_1.5   RWeka_0.4-28   openNLP_0.2-6  NLP_0.1-9     
[7] rJava_0.9-8   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] openNLPdata_1.5.3-2 parallel_3.3.0      tools_3.3.0         Rcpp_0.12.5         slam_0.1-34        
[6] grid_3.3.0          knitr_1.13          RWekajars_3.9.0-1
```